# Searching dates inside a file with Batch

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I have one query:

I want to find some dates inside a file, with Batch.

I've the following code:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (%path%\%file%) do (
    echo %%a | findstr /I "Date:"
 )
ECHO.
PAUSE
PAUSE
```

With this code I'm able to get the first date that appears in the file, but then the script finishes, and I want to get all the dates presents in the content of the file, not only one.

Have I to modify the for structure or use another command (instead of findstr)?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you get if you try like that `@for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (Type "%path%\%file%" ^| findstr /I "Date:") do (echo %%a)`

Comment: The code you have posted is unlikely to work, unless you are running it when your current working directory is `C:\Windows\System32`, _(which is usually the case when running As administrator)_. The reason for that is you appear to be using a variable named `path`. `%Path%` is a very important environment variable, and you have changed it, by defining the location of your source file as its value. This means that your script will be unlikely to locate `findstr.exe` because it will look in the current directory for it, and in `%path%`, appending each extension in `%PATHEXT%`.

Comment: @Hackoo this solution didn't work :(

Comment: @Compo sorry in my original code I assigned other name to the vars, don't exist path and file. I think that is not the problem.

Comment: Post all of the actual batch file then, instead of leaving us to guess. We cannot assist you with your issue unless we can reproduce what you have, and understand exactly the environment you're using it in, and how you are running the batch file. Please edit your question, to provide the missing information, and also an example using the code from @Hackoo, which you say isn't working, so that we can properly assist you.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont need to use the dates in variables and just want to output them, then just do this at rhe cli

```
TYPE "%path%\%file%" | FIND /I "Date:"
```

If you need to find eatch date and then do something else with it using a temp variable (and assuming there is only one `:` in the line with the date, and nothing else follows the date, you could do this in a `cmd` script

```
@(SETLOCAL
  ECHO OFF
)

 CALL :Main

( ENDLOCAL
EXIT /b )

:Main
  For /F "Tokens=1* delims=:" %%A IN (`
    TYPE "%path%\%file%" | FIND /I "Date:"
  ') DO (
    REM if you need all the characters aftrr "Date:" we can simply use this next line:
 
    SET "Date_Tmp_Full=%%~B"

    REM. If there may be whitespace around the value after "Date:" we can use rhe following method instead to trim it instead.

    For /F "tokens=*" %%_ IN ('echo %%~B') DO (
      SET "Date_Tmp=%%~_" )

     REM Your other code can go here, or you can call a function to do more instead.
     REM
     REM
  )
```